# Laravel Queue not calling jobs

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-sqs

I want to create new job which will be called by Amazon SQS and using Laravel Queue to push queues.

Currently, I have one job that works perfectly, but when I create another job as below, it has not been called.

```
class SimpleJob
{
    public function fire($job, $data)
    {
        DB::table('product_prices')
            ->insert(array('product_id' => 1557,'price' => 100));
        $this->success();
    }

    private function success()
    {
        $this->job->delete();
    }

    private function fail($messages = array())
    {
        Log::error('Job processing fail', $messages);
        $this->job->delete();
    }
}
```

I did read this [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues) but still cannot figure it out.

I am sure that SQS really sent a message since the old job can still be called.

Apart from creating job class and put everything in fire(), what else I need to do when creating new jobs?

This is Laravel 4.2.

Comment: Aside from creating the class you also need to push the job onto the queue with `Queue::push('SimpleJob');`.

Comment: @Bogdan I did push the job with Queue::push('SimpleJob'); but still not working

Comment: are you listening to the queue with ```php artisan queue:listen``` ?